# How CreateToolhelp32Snapshot with TH32CS_SNAPHEAPLIST interacts between 64 and 32 bit processes

Tags: c, winapi

I'm calling CreateToolhelp32Snapshot with the TH32CS_SNAPHEAPLIST flag then using (Heap32First/Heap32Next to traverse the heap listing).

This seems to work okay between processes built for the same architecture (32 or 64 bit) but I get odd results when calling 'inter architecture'. This makes sense for 32 bit, in fact it is documented:

If the specified process is a 64-bit process and the caller is a 32-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299). I appreciate this may just be expected behaviour, but I can't see it documented for the opposite direction.

So, for 64 to 32 bit I will see only 2 heaps for a process that returned upwards of 10 for 32 to 32.

I don't know if these are heaps being used by wow64 but my questions is this:

**How do I get the 32 bit process heap listing from a 64 bit process?**

Any information on the heap discrepancy would be a bonus.

Comment: I get 25 heaps from a 32-bit caller and 2 heaps from a 64-bit caller, and none of them overlap.  Most likely a WOW64 issue; I guess Microsoft didn't bother implementing this.  Easiest route is to delegate it out to a 32-bit helper process.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful, if I get chance I will try and look at the difference in calls, but you are right, a helper process is probably the easiest solution.